# How do I override the motion detection so that light will stay off?

Tags: switch

I installed the motion sensor lights in my boys bedrooms because they never turn off the lights.  However, I quickly realized that the motion detection isn't ideal after bed time when I go to check on them.  Is there a way to keep it off at night?

Comment: Shine a night light at the photo sensor at night or put it on a switch.  Think what want is a light with a timer that turns it off after a set time, like snooze on a radio.

Comment: Throwing a bunch of technology at a discipline problem never made sense to me. If they can't remember to turn the lights off, take the bulbs away. Otherwise, set a phone reminder and do it yourself. You should be using LED bulbs anyway, which use negligible power. This dad's $.02.

Comment: Is the light turning on automatically, or never turning off? Can you provide the model of sensor switch? Some models include a toggle for modes, and only turn off automatically, but can only be turned on by pressing a button.

Comment: I put a post-it note in front of the sensor to temporarily disable it.

Comment: Burning 1 watt 24x7 costs $1/**year**.  In an age of 9 watt LEDs (less if you go with Dubai LEDs) *and cable TV boxes that use [35 watts **at idle**](https://www.cordcuttersnews.com/cable-tv-boxes-raise-your-power-bill-by-almost-100-a-year/)*,  "turn off the lights" *is no longer* the place to teach that particular life lesson.  Tell them about Dubai LEDs and say if they get some, they can leave the lights on anytime they like.

Comment: No indication, @Harper-ReinstateMonica, that it's about finances (if I wanted to lower my electric bill, I'd shut down computers, but I don't give two hoots), but discipline (do what you're told to do) and habit, plus not waking the kids up with automatic lights turning on in the middle of the night when mom/dad check in on them.

Comment: Good call, @dandavis, except that the glue dries out, and somebody has to remember to post-it _before_ the kids fall asleep, since the act of adding the blocker in the middle of the night will probably trigger the motion sensor in the first place.

Comment: @FreeMan Just saying if you want to teach discipline, teach it on something that matters.  Fixating on a few watts of energy is like fixating on rotating all the cans and bottles on kitchen shelves with the labels forward.  You don't want the kids growing up to see the lesson as the futility of pleasing eccentric/OCD people.

Comment: a reasonable point, @Harper-ReinstateMonica, but discipline is discipline. Develop the habits of doing the right thing in the little things (where there is small consequence for failure in young kids), and they'll be in the habit of doing the right thing in the big things when they're older and the consequences are greater. _bzzzzt. Fwop! Whoa!!! How did we end up on [parenting.se]???_

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be a timer. A motion sensor works well in many places, but aside from going *on* when it shouldn't (when you check on the kids), it also will go *off* when it shouldn't - e.g., kids sitting and reading with the only motion being an occasional flip of a page.

There are plenty of options, such as this [Woods timer for up to 60 minutes](https://amzn.to/3kChBNO):

[image: Woods timer]

Comment: Have the boys hook them up themselves.   If they are old enough that you think they should turn off the lights, they are old enough to put together some components.   Putting together components is what turns a boy into a man.  They will add time to the timer when they need the light, just as I add time to the vent fan in the bathroom when needed.  Best - different colored lights, each with its own timer.

Comment: _Excellent_ suggestion, @Willk!! Teaches them how to do common household maintenance chores as well as the _safe_ way to do them.